# Integrate $\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dx}{\left(x+1\right)\sqrt{x^{2}+2x+2}}$

Tags: integration

calculate the following integral:

> $$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dx}{\left(x+1\right)\sqrt{x^{2}+2x+2}}$$

let $x+1↦u$:
$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dx}{\left(x+1\right)\sqrt{x^{2}+2x+2}}=\int_{ }^{ }\frac{du}{u\sqrt{u^{2}+1}}$$

let $u^2+1↦v$:
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dv}{\left(v-1\right)\sqrt{v}}$$

substitute $\sqrt{v}↦t$:
$$=\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dt}{t^{2}-1}=$$$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dt}{t-1}-\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dt}{t+1}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\left|\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right|\right)+c=$$$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{v}-1}{\sqrt{v}+1}\right|\right)+c=$$$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{u^{2}+1}-1}{\sqrt{u^{2}+1}+1}\right|\right)+c=$$$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\left|\frac{\sqrt{\left(x+1\right)^{2}+1}-1}{\sqrt{\left(x+1\right)^{2}+1}+1}\right|\right)+c$$

but I'm not sure if my computation is right , can someone check this and if it's not right please mentions where  I was wrong.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says this here $$\frac{\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{x^2+2
   x+2}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: I would suggest using the https://www.integral-calculator.com/ .

Comment: @Absurd I didn't get the "why not" part?

Comment: It is not the simplest way, but your computation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ t=\frac1{1+x}$,

$$\int_{ }^{ }\frac{dx}{\left(x+1\right)\sqrt{x^{2}+2x+2}}
=-\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}=- \sinh^{-1} t + C$$

Comment: can you tell me wheter mine is right or not?

Comment: @Absurd - I checked your derivation, which is correct. It can be simplified, though, as I edited to the answer. It is equivalent to the result I provided.